# Extracting files with Japanese characters from a zip archive

Tags: perl, zip, special-characters, extract

Everything inside the zip file has a Japanese name (e.g. the directories inside, pdfs inside etc.). When I tried using
[`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip)
or
[`Archive::Extract`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Extract),
it fails at a single point (Input/Output error) while trying to create a directory with a apanese name.

Is there any way to deal with this without having to write my unzipping module?

```
use warnings;

use POSIX;
use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use Sys::Hostname;
use Archive::Extract;
use File::Path;

my $filename = '42108e01b86ed61ed18c29066254b5b9.zip';
my $dest_dir = "test_site/pk";

use Archive::Zip;

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();

unless ( $zip->read( $filename ) == AZ_OK ) {
    die "Error Reading Zip File !";
}

foreach my $m ( $zip->members() ) {

    print "Member $m:\n  ";

    my $err = $zip->extractMemberWithoutPaths( $m, "$dest_dir/" . $m->fileName );
    print "Error: $err" if $err;
    print $/;
}
```

#### Error is:

> Input/output error at Archive/Zip/Member.pm line 485.

Comment: With `use Archive::Zip qw(AZ_OK)`, the code runs for me without errors on Linux and Windows. The file names on Windows become double encoded mojibake.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I suggest that you update your installation of `Archive::Zip`. In the current version, line 485 of `Archive/Zip/Member.pm` is a blank line.

Comment: In my installation, at #485 it tries to create a directory. It is a part of `extractToFileNamed` subroutine and the exact line is `mkpath (dirname($name) ); `.

Comment: For the zip i mentioned, it extracts to a folder with Japanese characters (when extracted using WinZip). I understand that it is failing due to encoding issues. All I want to ask is if there is a way to deal with the issue without me having to write my own unzipping module.

Comment: Well, what happens when you update the module? Did you miss that suggestion above?

Comment: I tried. It does not work. The error is the same (while making a directory). It lies in `member.pm#511`.

Comment: This means the problem is with the archive file. Can you help us somehow to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The zip extracts to a directory with japanese name and the directory contains pdfs with japanese names.